# Changing color for overlapping scatters in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to visualize a prediction method with the help of seaborns `lmplot`, I have the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1, 1], 'col2': [3, 4, 3, 4], 'col3': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

sns.lmplot('col1', 'col2', data =df, hue='col3', fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={"s": 10})
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

The problem is that one line is completely hidden now:

[image]

How can I change these scatters? That the rows with the same col1 and col2 but different col3 (where it is only 0 or 1) are highlighted in a different color (e.g. in red)? Best solutions would be without overwrite the orginal dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change marker styles:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1, 1], 'col2': [3, 4, 3, 4], 'col3': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

sns.lmplot('col1', 'col2', data =df, hue='col3', fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={"s": 200, "alpha":.7}, markers=['o','x'])
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Really nice one! Thx!

Comment: how to prevent this color mix for overalapping bars in histplot?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala Do you have a post that you want to reference?  Can you create a post showing the behavior you want to eliminate?

Comment: @ScottBoston, i have opened a post and here it is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70802735/retain-legend-color-or-some-indication-for-overlapping-bars-in-seaborn-histplot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning another color to overlapping data points, I would personally prefer to introduce some *transparency* by setting [alpha blending value](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

I also increased the marker size.

```
sns.lmplot('col1', 'col2', data=df, hue='col3', fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={"s": 100, 'alpha': 0.3})
```

Comment: @PV8 glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a new value of `col3` for these cases:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1, 1], 'col2': [3, 4, 3, 4], 'col3': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.loc[df["col1"] == df["col2"], "col3"] = df["col3"].max() + 1

sns.lmplot('col1', 'col2', data =df, hue='col3', fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={"s": 10})
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
```

Comment: do you mean `df.loc`instead of col?

Comment: `df.col`does not exists, and with `df.loc`nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

One option, which I find, but I do not prefer is:

```
import numpy as np
df2 = df.copy()
df2['col3'] = np.where(df2.duplicated(subset=['col1', 'col2']), 2, df2['col3'])
sns.lmplot('col1', 'col2', data =df2, hue='col3', fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={"s": 10})

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 10)
plt.show()
```