# have some indication for overlapping bars in seaborn histplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

In histograms plotted with seaborn, when the bars overlap becuase of using `hue`, the colors change, often indistinguishable. That makes it hard to explain the plots to people. this gets increasingly difficult when there are 10 classes drawn with gradient and understanding which color is on which gets harder. So, how do I show on plots or in legend that the resulting colors are because of the overalap of multiple bars.

```
# imports
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

# getting the data
iris = load_iris(as_frame=True)['frame']

# make the histogram
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20, 5)})
sns.histplot(data=iris, x='sepal length (cm)', hue='target')
plt.show()
```

that displays this with overlapping in highlited area:
[image]

I would like to stick to using histograms.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did @mozway solution below solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the transparency using the `alpha=1` parameter:

```
sns.histplot(data=iris, x='sepal length (cm)', hue='target', alpha=1)
```

Note, however, that if bars from series displayed in the back might become invisible if the bars of the series on top of it are higher.

[image: histplot]

An alternative then would be to have one graph per group using `displot`:

```
sns.displot(data=iris, x='sepal length (cm)', row='target', alpha=1, kind='hist')
```

[image: displot]

*NB. I used `iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')` to load the dataset, the the different names in the graphs.*

```
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns.histplot(data=iris, x='sepal_length', hue='species', alpha=1)
sns.displot(data=iris, x='sepal_length', row='species', alpha=1, kind='hist')
```

Comment: Maybe `multiple='stack'` or `multiple='dodge'` could also be considered as `histplot` parameter?

Comment: @mozway, thanks for the answer. is there a way to reduce the transparecy of only the portion of the bars overlapped?

Comment: @Naveen, use any float between 0 (full transparent) and 1 (opaque) as `alpha`

Comment: that decreases the transparency of all the bars in the plot. i wanted to know, if there's a way to vary the transparency of the overlapped places.

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly ;) No, you can't directly. You can access the patches in the raw matplotlib plot and change them, but you'd either have to do it manually or to write your own function.